# Help - Formulação de lógica - SQL, PHP, HTML

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Tenho uma tabela no banco com cadastro de equipes, onde cada linha corresponde a um funcionário e sua respectiva equipe. Por exemplo,

id_equipe, funcionário

1, Mario

1, Sérgio

2, João

2, José

Quero trazer os dados na tela em uma tabela de forma que cada linha corresponda a cada equipe, e a coluna funcionários seja uma concatenação dos nomes. Isto é:

id_equipe, funcionários

1,        Mario,Sérgio

2,        João, José

O que tenho até o momento:

```html
 <table id="myDatatable" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                          <th>Nome Equipe</th>
                          <th>Funcionários</th>
                          <th>Ações</th>
                        </tr>
                      </thead>

                  <?php
                    

                     $id_agencia = $_SESSION['id_agencia'];
                   


              $pdo = Conexao::getInstance();



                $dados = $pdo->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT(nome_equipe),id_equipe,id_eletricista FROM quadro WHERE id_agencia=:id AND status=1 GROUP BY nome_equipe");
                $dados->bindParam(':id',$id_agencia, PDO::PARAM_INT);

                $dados->execute();

                        if($dados->rowCount()>=1){

                            echo '<tbody>';
                             while($table = $dados->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){
                          
                                                
                              echo '<tr>';
                              
                              
                              $id_equipe=$table->id_equipe;
                              
                              echo'<td>'.$table->nome_equipe.'</td>';
                              echo'<td>'.$table->id_eletricista.'</td>';
                              
                              echo '<td><a class="btn btn-success" href="editando_equipe.php?id='.$id_equipe.'"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Editar</a>

                              <a class="btn btn-warning" href="Quadro/desativar_equipe.php?id='.$id_equipe.'&Acesso=0" title="Desativar equipe"><i class="fa fa-minus-circle"></i></a>


                              </td>';
                                                                               }
                              }
                                                                            


                                                    
                            
                                      
                        echo '</tr>';
                                            
                      echo '</tbody>';

                   
                    

                      ?>
                    </table>
                  </div>

                </div>
              </div>
                </div><!-- div da row anterior class="col-md-6 col-xs-12"-->
              </div>
```

Quem puder me dar dicas de como atingir esse objetivo, agradecerei muito!
Qualquer ajuda é bem vinda!

Comment: Resumindo: `SELECT id_equipe, GROUP_CONCAT( funcionario ) AS funcionarios FROM tabela GROUP BY id_equipe` - Ajuste para sua lógica. O importante é que o `GROUP BY` seja para o valor que se repete, e o `GROUP_CONCAT` aplicado no campo separado por vírgulas. Mais detalhes nos links azuis do fechamento.

Comment: Muito obrigada pela ajuda!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utilizando o `GROUP_CONCAT`, segue abaixo como você pode fazer a sua `query`:

```
SELECT nome_equipe, id_equipe, GROUP_CONCAT(funcionario) funcionarios
FROM quadro
WHERE id_agencia=:id AND status=1
GROUP BY id_equipe
```

Comment: Muito obrigada pela ajuda!